# What was "one more murder" that Voldemort was planning and talking about in GoF Ch. 1?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

From the *Goblet of Fire*, Chapter 1 (THE RIDDLE HOUSE):

> "If?" whispered the second voice. "If? If you follow the plan, Wormtail, the
>   Ministry need never know that anyone else has died. You will do it quietly and
>   without fuss; I only wish that i could do it myself, but in my present
>   condition...Come, Wormtail, one more death and our path to Harry
>   Potter is clear.
>   I am not asking you to do it alone. By that time, my faithful serant
>   will have rejoined us --"
>
> ...
>
> **"One more murder** ... my faithful servant at Hogwarts...Harry Potter is as good as
>   mine, Wormtail. It is decided. There will be no more argument. But
>   quiet...I think I hear Nagini..."

What was that "one more murder" that Voldemort was planning and
talking about? I can think of 5 possibilities (four actual and one
attempted murders in GoF) but none of them fit:

- *Bertha Jorkins*:   Was already dead, and her death discussed in
  that same conversation
- *Frank Bryce*: Doesn't seem to fit, since Voldemort didn't know he
  was around until **after Nagini told him**, several minutes later
  ("Nagini has interesting news, Wormtail," the vice said. "In-indeed,
  My Lord?" said Wormtail. "Indeed, yes," said the voice, "According to
  Nagini, there is an old Muggle
  standing right outside this room, listening to every word we say.")
- *Barty Crouch Sr:* Wasn't pre-planned (necesitated by him fighting
  off Imperius Curse placed by Jr. and escaping).
- *Cedric*: Wasn't planned - Harry was meant to end up in the graveyard alone.
- *Harry's attempted murder*: The murder spoken of here was meant to
  be **before** Harry was in Voldemort's hands.
- Also, as Xantec noted, it wasn't Moody, since he was needed alive for Crouch Jr.'s impersonation up till Harry's capture.

Comment: Dumbledore? Of course he meant to kill Harry in the cemetery, so the later plan with Draco in HBP doesn't really fit.

Comment: Alastor Moody? Although he wasn't meant to be killed before Harry, since Barty Crouch Jr needed him to keep making polyjuice potions.

Comment: FWIW, the text is different in this quote on the UK edition inwhich it is "One more curse" http://www.hp-lexicon.org/about/books/gf/differences-gf.html and taking "curse" over murder, perhaps it is the Imperius curse which Wormtail will cast on Bartemius Crouch.

Comment: I think it was harry. He didn't have him yet, so it was still to be committed.

Comment: @Xantec - yes, I agree, Moody was planned to be kept alive till then.

Comment: @NikolaiDante - worth an answer :)

Comment: I've expanded by comment into an answer.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In the UK edition of Goblet of Fire, the text is slightly different:

> "If?" whispered the second voice. "If? If you follow the plan, Wormtail, the
>   Ministry need never know that anyone else has died. You will do it quietly and
>   without fuss; I only wish that i could do it myself, but in my present
>   condition...Come, Wormtail, one more ***obstacle removed*** and our path to Harry
>   Potter is clear.
>   I am not asking you to do it alone. By that time, my faithful serant
>   will have rejoined us --"
>
> ...
>
> "One more ***curse***... my faithful servant at Hogwarts...Harry Potter is as good as
>   mine, Wormtail. It is decided. There will be no more argument. But
>   quiet...I think I hear Nagini..."

([source](http://www.hp-lexicon.org/about/books/gf/differences-gf.html))

In this context, the "one more curse" that Voldemort refers to is likely the Imperius curse which Wormtail will cast on Bartemius Crouch (Sr). Which enabled Barty Jr, (the faithful servant) to impersonate Moody at Hogwarts.

(And the "obstacle removed" could be the Imperius curse which Bartemius Crouch (Sr) was using to keep Barty Jr. in line, or perhaps the obstacle referred to was (the real) Moody.)

Comment: +1 - this sounds plausible, though i'd love a JKR confirmation

Comment: The problem with this being Bartemius Crouch (Sr) is that Voldemort says "I am not asking you to do it alone. By that time, my faithful servant will have rejoined us." The faithful servant he is referring to is Barty Crouch Jr. So it is one more curse (or death) that happens AFTER Barty Crouch Jr. has been released.

Comment: That is a pretty radical alteration of the text during localization.

Comment: I wonder why it was felt necessary to alter the text that much.

Comment: @Xantec - unfortunately, such alterations happen with alarming regularity - to the angst of many a writer (and often without their involvement at all)

Comment: I'm not sure that this fully answers the question - there's still this part of the quote: `If you follow the plan, Wormtail, the Ministry need never know that anyone else has died.` This implies that there's still one more murder to do...

Comment: I believe in the Uk edition died == disappeared. I'll check the book when I get home.

Comment: @NikolaiDante: Did you ever get home? :P

Answer (score 3):

I think it must refer to the capture of Moody.  Wormtail would never have been able to do that alone and would have needed Barty Crouch Jnr's help.  With the removal of the real Moody and his replacement with a fake the 'path to Harry Potter' was clear for Voldemort.  Yes they needed to enchant Barty Crouch Snr but I think Jnr had already taken care of this otherwise how would he have been able to come and see Voldemort.  All that would have been needed was for Barty Snr to have been watched to make sure he was still under control.